# cancel( reset the html ) button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to html, javascript, and css.
I do not know why, but my cancel button is not working at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<!-- set the page title and link with java script and css files -->
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hw4.css">
<script src="hw4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">Post to</td>

            <!-- create two post to buttons -->
            <td class="second"><input id="entire" type="radio" name="post"
                value="entire" checked>Entire Class <input type="radio"
                id="individual" name="post" value="individual">Individual
                Student(s)/instructor(s)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Select Folder(s)</td>
            <td class="second">
                <!-- create six homework checkboxes -->
                <div class="hw">
                    <input id="hw1" type="checkbox"><label for="hw1">hw1</label>
                    <input id="hw2" type="checkbox"><label for="hw2">hw2</label>
                    <input id="hw3" type="checkbox"><label for="hw3">hw3</label>
                    <input id="hw4" type="checkbox"><label for="hw4">hw4</label>
                    <input id="hw5" type="checkbox"><label for="hw5">hw5</label>
                    <input id="hw6" type="checkbox"><label for="hw6">hw6</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Summary
                <div style="font: 10px Arial">(100 charactors or less)</div>
            </td>

                <td class="second"><input id="summary" type="text" size="25"
                value="Enter a one line summary...!" onclick="this.value='';"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Details</td>

            <!-- create detail text area. -->
            <td class="second"><textarea id="details" name="textarea"
                    rows="10" cols="50" wrap='off'></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Posting Options</td>

            <!-- create two option check boxes -->
            <td><input id="option1" type="checkbox"> Make this an
                announcement (note appears on the course page)</br> <input id="option2"
                type="checkbox"> Send email notifications immediately
                (bypassing student's email preferences, if neccesory)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td>
                <input id="post" type="submit" value="Post My Note!" onClick="check()">
                <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
            </td>
    </table>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

when I run this code, everything works well, but the cancel button is not working.
I think I did something wrong, because it worked like 30 mins ago, but
now it is not working at all and I cannot figure out what is wrong...!!

Comment: Where is form tag. Reset button clearing only form

Comment: My first thought add defer attribute to your script tag, it will execute your js after the page loads. But without js it is difficult to find the source of your problem. Make a fiddle please, as Amy asked:)

Comment: As an aside, reset buttons are from the devil.

Answer (score 4):

You have no `form` tag. A reset-button clears values inside a form.

2 Solutions:

- Wrap your input-elements inside a `<form><!-- elements here --></form>`
- Write a piece of script to clear the elements you want to clear when you click on the clear-button.

Comment: @TheProvost you can see the comments also for who answering first :)

Comment: Thx, in fairness, Amy and I were seconds apart. *edit* just like now in this comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Reset button only working for form tag. So please add form tag in your code as I shown in demo.

```js
<script src="hw4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <table>
  <form>
        <tr>
            <td class="first">Post to</td>

            <!-- create two post to buttons -->
            <td class="second"><input id="entire" type="radio" name="post"
                value="entire" checked>Entire Class <input type="radio"
                id="individual" name="post" value="individual">Individual
                Student(s)/instructor(s)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Select Folder(s)</td>
            <td class="second">
                <!-- create six homework checkboxes -->
                <div class="hw">
                    <input id="hw1" type="checkbox"><label for="hw1">hw1</label>
                    <input id="hw2" type="checkbox"><label for="hw2">hw2</label>
                    <input id="hw3" type="checkbox"><label for="hw3">hw3</label>
                    <input id="hw4" type="checkbox"><label for="hw4">hw4</label>
                    <input id="hw5" type="checkbox"><label for="hw5">hw5</label>
                    <input id="hw6" type="checkbox"><label for="hw6">hw6</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Summary
                <div style="font: 10px Arial">(100 charactors or less)</div>
            </td>

                <td class="second"><input id="summary" type="text" size="25"
                value="Enter a one line summary...!" onclick="this.value='';"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Details</td>

            <!-- create detail text area. -->
            <td class="second"><textarea id="details" name="textarea"
                    rows="10" cols="50" wrap='off'></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="first">Posting Options</td>

            <!-- create two option check boxes -->
            <td><input id="option1" type="checkbox"> Make this an
                announcement (note appears on the course page)</br> <input id="option2"
                type="checkbox"> Send email notifications immediately
                (bypassing student's email preferences, if neccesory)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>

            <td>
                <input id="post" type="submit" value="Post My Note!" onClick="check()">
                <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
            </td>
                 </form>
    </table>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: While the lack of `form` element is indeed the cause, the problem should not be fixed using invalid HTML. A `form` element is not allowed as a child of `table`; they can be nested the other way around.